# System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I hosted my WCF Service using Windows Service, but when I call the WCF method I get the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException: The HTTP service located
>   at
>   http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/RahatWcfServiceLibrary/ServerDateTime/
>   is too busy.  ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned
>   an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

The App.Config in my WCF Service and Windows Service is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="RahatWcfServiceLibrary.ServerDateTimeBehavior" name="RahatWcfServiceLibrary.ServerDateTime">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="RahatWcfServiceLibrary.IServerDateTime">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/RahatWcfServiceLibrary/ServerDateTime/mex" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RahatWcfServiceLibrary.ServerDateTimeBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="60" maxConcurrentSessions="60"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding **'/mex'** at the end of endpoint address in App.Config file in Windows Application that consumes the service.

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/RahatWcfServiceLibrary/ServerDateTime/mex"
```